# Can anyone help me close this program in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

```vb
MsgBox ("Do you want to start the autoclicker?", vbOkOnly, "Autoclicker")
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\Fun.vbs""")
MsgBox ("Do you want to stop the autoclicker?", vbOkOnly, "Autoclicker")
```

Comment: Better code format. A longer description of the intended use of the code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each objItem in colItems
    'msgbox objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.CommandLine
    If objItem.name = "Calculator.exe" then objItem.terminate
Next
```

This kills calculator.exe. Change it to wscript.exe. You might want to check command line if you just want to kill fun.vbs.

Comment: Thank you this really helps

Answer (score 0):

The following routine kills all processes whose command lines contain a specified string. The 3 lines below the routine are for testing it. We pause the routine by showing a message box and when you dismiss the message box, we kill the script instance, so the second message box doesn't show up. When you use it, you want to replace the last 3 lines with

```
KillProcesses "Fun.vbs"
```

I'd be careful using this and specify as much of the command line as possible to make sure I absolutely, positively match only the processes I want to terminate. You can modify the Task Manager and add a column to show the command line for every running process. In the routine below, the search in command line is case-insensitive.

```
Option Explicit

Sub KillProcesses(strPartOfCommandLine)
    Dim colProcesses
    Dim objProcess
    Dim lReturn


    ' Get list of running processes using WMI
    Set colProcesses = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

    For Each objProcess in colProcesses
        If (Instr(1, objProcess.Commandline, strPartOfCommandLine, vbTextCompare) <> 0) Then
            lReturn = objProcess.Terminate(0)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Msgbox "Before being killed"
KillProcesses "KillProcesses.vbs"
Msgbox "After being killed"
```

Answer (score 0):

I made before a script that ask you what vbscript did you want to kill and log the result into file.

So just, give a try :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Titre,Copyright,fso,ws,NomFichierLog,temp,PathNomFichierLog,OutPut,Count,strComputer
Copyright = "[© Hackoo © 2014 ]"
Titre = " Process "& DblQuote("Wscript.exe") &" running "
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject( "Wscript.Shell" )
NomFichierLog="Process_WScript.txt"
temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%temp%")
PathNomFichierLog = temp & "\" & NomFichierLog
Set OutPut = fso.CreateTextFile(temp & "\" & NomFichierLog,1)
Count = 0 
strComputer = "."
Call Find("wscript.exe")
Call Explorer(PathNomFichierLog)
'***************************************************************************************************
Function Explorer(File)
    Dim ws
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws.run "Explorer "& File & "\",1,True
end Function
'***************************************************************************************************
Sub Find(MyProcess)
    Dim colItems,objItem,Processus,Question
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name like '%"& MyProcess &"%' AND NOT commandline like '%" & wsh.scriptname & "%'",,48)
    For Each objItem in colItems
        Count= Count + 1
        Processus = Mid(objItem.CommandLine,InStr(objItem.CommandLine,""" """) + 2) 'Extraction of the commandline script path
        Processus = Replace(Processus,chr(34),"")
        Question = MsgBox ("Did you want to stop this script : "& DblQuote(Processus) &" ?" ,VBYesNO+VbQuestion,Titre+Copyright)
        If Question = VbYes then
            objItem.Terminate(0)'Kill this process
            OutPut.WriteLine DblQuote(Processus)
        else
            Count= Count - 1 'decrement the counter -1
        End if
    Next
OutPut.WriteLine String(100,"*")
OutPut.WriteLine count & Titre & " were stopped !"
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```