# Restart explorer.exe with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, windows-10, excel-2016

I'm trying to add a registry key to combine Windows when the taskbar is full. After that I need to close explorer.exe and start again.

Killing the explorer process is easy enough with

```
shell "taskkill /f /im explorer.exe"
```

I'm having trouble starting it again

I tried

```
Shell "explorer.exe"
```

and

```
Shell "cmd.exe /c explorer.exe"
```

Both of these open an explorer window but don't start the process with taskbar.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it

In order for it to work in windows 10 you have to call the full file path to explorer.exe

> Shell("C:\Windows\explorer.exe")

This properly opens the explorer process along with taskbar and desktop

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/fd9f9f0f-37f7-42ba-8953-17e51ef5168f/start-explorerexe-with-vba?forum=excel) solution was one of the first results on Google. Did you try to run this in the same Sub?

```
Sub Rumi()
    Shell ("cmd.exe /c taskkill /f /im explorer.exe")

    Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    Shell "cmd.exe /c explorer.exe"
End Sub
```

Comment: Well not In the same sub but I did stumble upon that I don't think I need application.Wait but I'll give it a try anyway and tell you somethin

Comment: Doesn't work, all it does is open a explorer window, and desktop and taskbar are not restored

Comment: See last answer on this page. Programmers don't run user's commands - they program. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120146/can-anyone-help-me-close-this-program-in-vbscript